# GraphQL query: only include field if not null

Tags: graphql

Does GraphQL have the possibility for the client to tell the server that it wants a field only if that field is not `null`?

Given the query

```
query HeroAndFriends {
  hero {
    name
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

the response should then look like

```
{
  "data": {
    "hero": {
      "friends": [
        {
          "name": "Luke Skywalker"
        },
        {
          "name": "Han Solo"
        },
        {
          "name": "Leia Organa"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "data": {
    "hero": {
      "name": null,
      "friends": [
        {
          "name": "Luke Skywalker"
        },
        {
          "name": "Han Solo"
        },
        {
          "name": "Leia Organa"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible without violating the GraphQL specification?

Comment: Just curious to know: what is the use-case of this behaviour?

Comment: @AhmadFerdousBinAlam I have a Kotlin data class with default (non-null) values that I don't want to be overwritten when deserializing.

Comment: @Ahmad Ferdous, regarding the use-case, what if the server returns arrays of items that have sparse data? like each object has many fields, only a few of which actually contain something rather than null. Would it not be better to exclude those fields from the payload to decrease the overall size of the api response?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know this is not possible, there are [directives](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/#sec-Language.Directives) like @skip and @include. Directives but they need a variable, I think you can make your case with the graphql team to extend the directives to only include the field if it's not null.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this ES6 syntax in front-end:

```
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => (data[key] == null) && delete data[key]);
```