# Graphql query only not null objects

Tags: express, meteor, graphql, graphql-js

im trying to perform a query like this:

```
{
 people{
   pet{
     name
   }
 }
}
```

result:

```
{
 "people": {
   "pet": null
 }
},
{
 "people": {
   "pet": {
     name: "steve"
  }
 }
}
```

What i want is to get only people that contains a pet, is there any way to achieve this not coding on my resolver ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451910/graphql-query-only-include-field-if-not-null

Comment: You can have a look at this https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/1053#issuecomment-605328928

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible the way you describe. GraphQL will call resolve functions to fetch the data. If you don't want certain data in your response, you have to filter it somewhere on the server. The only thing you have control over is the query, the schema and the resolve functions.

There is no way to express your requirement purely in the query. If you put it in the schema, you would no longer be able to query for people without pets. So the only way to do it is to write it in your resolve function. You could for example add a boolean argument called `hasPet` to your people field, and do this in the resolver:

```
people(root, { hasPet }){
  // get allPeople
  if (typeof hasPet === 'undefined'){
    return allPeople
  }
  return allPeople.filter((person) => person.hasPet() === hasPet)
}
```

The unfortunate thing is that this will require you to 'look ahead' and figure out if a person has a pet in the first place, but if you cache backend or DB requests with something like DataLoader, this isn't actually costly, because you would have to fetch the pet anyway. This way you just fetch it a bit earlier.

If you're fetching your people from a database, it would of course make sense to already filter them there, and not in the resolve function.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, it is possible with the `filter: { pet: {ne: null} }` filtering:

```
query allPeople(filter: { people: { pet: {ne: null} } }) {
    people {
       pet
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any documentation reference for this? I wonder whether this filter functionality is specific to a particular stack, as it doesn't seem to work in [Apollo Studio Star Wars API](https://studio.apollographql.com/public/star-wars-swapi/explorer)

Comment: @Philzen Actually I've been looking at `gatsby`'s [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/#filter) - Don't know why it doesn't work on apollo and didn't find much info in their docs unfortunately. Hopefully this resource might help you find the needed info.