# Exclude null values from GraphQL query

Tags: neo4j, graphql, retool

**Disclaimer, I am still a noob in GraphQL.**

Apologies for the long post, but I need to give as much information as possible to explain my issue.

I am currently trying to query my **Neo4j** using **GraphQL** and then tabulate the data using **ReTool**.

I managed to do most of the work but when I query the database, I also get the null values.

You can access the sandbox below to test yourself a probable solution.
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-marco-coy3k

The query I am using is the following:

```
query {
  people{
    child{
      firstname{
        name
      }
      middlename{
        name
      }
      lastname{
        name
      }
      phone{
        name
      }
      email{
        name
      }
      dob{
        name
      }
      eid{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Response]

As you can see, I get back a mixture of null and none-null values.

What I would like to get back is the children that has data in them and ignore the null ones. The reason for that is when I try to populate my table, the null values appear there too.

I need to stress on the fact that I'd still need to retrieve "child" even if one or more of the objects are null as depicted in the image below:

[image: The middlename is null which is completely fine]

While doing some research, I noticed that other people have the same problem I am facing ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969096/graphql-query-only-not-null-objects)), but most replies said there is no direct solution to this problem, many talked about adjusting the resolver which I am not sure how to do. The resolver file was already set by Neo4j Sandbox automatically and I don't know how to adjust it.

To provide more information regarding the root cause of the problem, you can check the Neo4j schema below:

[image: Neo4j Schema]

As you can see, the two-person nodes that have the relationship MASTER_OF and CHILD_OF are similar.
When I query  `people{child{firstname name}...}`
I get the value of the node that has a IN CHILD_OF relationship and null for the node that has IN MASTER_OF relationship.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are not sure what each value will return null : it may or it may not be null. In this case it is impossible to adjust your schema to only contain non-null values. You would have to deal with it in the frontend and completely exclude null values there.

Comment: You're correct. I have some child which are completely null. And some which have some of their objects as null. Finding a backend solution is impossible. So as you've mentioned, I found a way to solve it in the frontend.